# Use MS Word to remove random paragraph breaks in text?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a text file with random paragraph breaks in it.

What it looks like now:

```
The quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog. The quick
brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The brown fox jumps over the lazy
dog.
```

What I want it to look like:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I can find these random breaks using "^$^p" in the find and replace tool. (any letter + paragraph mark)

However I have no idea how to fix this on a mass scale (it's quite a big file). I have little knowledge of macros, but if anyone can give me some example code or idea of how to proceed, I might be able to figure it out.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Tick "Use wildcards", put `(?>)^13` in Find what, put `\1 ` in Replace with, and click Replace all?

Comment: @GSerg I have no idea what sorcery this is, but thank you so much it worked perfectly!

Comment: [Link to the sorcery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?NS=WINWORD&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZWD160&HelpId=33&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) opens if you click `?` in the Find and Replace window.